# Bottle drying after sanitisation?

Tags: equipment, sanitation, bottles

When sanitising and using a bottle tree, should I wait for bottles to dry completely or can I use them just rinsed? The Youngs sanitiser I'm using says items should be used within 1 hour of being cleaned. There's no way - at UK temps - that they will air-dry in an hour!

Comment: Youngs is a UK brewery, so you'd hope they'd take the climate into consideration!

Comment: @mdma True.. but common sense can't be trusted! What do you do with your bottles? Or are you a keg/barrel sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try to find out what is in your Young's sanitizer. Do they claim it is a 'no-rinse' sanitizer?

If so, go ahead and bottle in the still wet bottles.

If not, you could boil some water and use that water to rinse (hard work)...

I usually use Iodophor, which is a non-rinse in the proper concentration.

On the few times I used something that I didn't want in contact with my beer, I went against common sense and used plain tap water (which is pretty clean in Finland). Didn't have any issues in my bottled beer so far, but can't really recommend that approach. Be safe and boil your rinse water   :)